# C# Function Array

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I make program, from a text file (`.txt`) I must with function `split` cut the line on worlds. But I do not know how this world write in function while to the array and work with this.

There is code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("text.txt", FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] slova = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');

        }



        sr.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand you question

Comment: I don't understand you, what do you want to do with the `string[]` of each line?

Comment: post example text which you are trying to parse

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are calling [`StreamReader.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) twice. This method advances the reader to the next line. So the first call will initialize `line` with the current line and the next call here will read the next line:

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)        // <-- first ReadLine
{
    string[] slova = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');// <-- second ReadLine
}
```

So just use the variable instead

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] slova = line.Split(';');
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string filePath = "text.txt";
char wordsSeparator = ';';
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
   IEnumerable<string> words = line.Split(new [] {wordsSeparator});
   // TODO: process words?!
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question(which is absolutely unclear)? You can put the `// TODO: process words?!` also behind OP's `sr.ReadLine().Split(';');`. You are just showing a different way to do the same.

Comment: But he's using it already: `sr.ReadLine().Split(';');`

Comment: My bad, I was thinking that he do not know how to use split but finally - the problem that I didn't know that `String.Split()` has such an overload which accepts _single_ character, and I've shown an other way of reading file since think it is more easy to read than using streams. So downvotes is a good study for such answers!

Comment: @TimSchmelter one crucial way in which this code differ is that this coode uses `line` in the while loop while the OPs code does not.